# val() in firefox sets wrong value, deletes one white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have an ajax code and in the success I have this code:

```
//success
    alert(data.now);    //1
    alert($('#myTextArea').val());    //2
    $('#myTextbox').val(data.now);
    alert(data.now);    //3
    alert($('#myTextArea').val());    //4
```

`//1` alerts this text:

```
'<p>hello how  are you </p><p>tnx im fine</p>'
```

(There are two empty spaces between 'how' and 'are')

`//2` alerts empty string. My `textarea` is empty still.

`//3` alerts this text:

```
'<p>hello how  are you</p><p>tnx im fine</p>'
```

(There are two empty spaces between 'how' and 'are')

`//4`:

```
'<p>hello how are you</p><p>tnx im fine</p>'
```

There is just one empty space.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Most browsers remove extra whitespace. Do you have a need for 2 spaces?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, I want to show the text just as it is.

Comment: @Srcee Then you need to use non-breaking spaces: `&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing empty spaces with "\u00a0" fixed my problem. Replacing them with " " worked in console, but not in my program.

Answer (score 7):

Use css `white-space` style to preserve the white space inside an element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space

```
  .my_element {
    white-space: pre; /* or other pre- styles*/
  }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5UWFB/2/

Comment: You could also use `&nbsp;` instead of a space in places where `pre` would cause other white-space to be visible that you didn't want visible.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem.